# In postman tests. how to verify response body in a duration value

Tags: postman

I have a request that returns a response body with:

```json
{ 
  "age" : 20
}
```

I want to verify that the age value is between 19 and 30. How can I do this with Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this with one line of code:

```
pm.test("Check age is between 19 and 30", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().age).gte(19).lte(30);
});
```

- `gte()` = greater than or equal to
- `lte()` = less than or equal to

if you just want greater than or less than, you can use `gt()` and `lt()`

Answer (score 0):

On the Tests tab for your request you can use either of these tests (they do the same thing). The first test reads better and makes use of native `most` and `least` chai.js constructs, while the second one tests the `age` boundary as a boolean and then checks that it is true

```js
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
const age = Number(jsonData.age)

pm.test("Check age is between 19 and 30 - most/least", function () {
    
    pm.expect(age).to.be.at.most(30);
    pm.expect(age).to.be.at.least(19);
});

pm.test("Check age is between 19 and 30 - boolean check", function () {
    const ageCheck = age >= 19 && age <= 30
    pm.expect(ageCheck).to.be.true
});
```

If this is the first time you're looking into Postman tests, this is what it should look like in the Tests tab of your request:

[image]